# Has this model theory definition been studied in the literature?

Tags: definition, model-theory

Let $S$ be a non-empty set. I define the "total structure" of $S$ to be the following structure. First, there is a distinct symbol for every constant $s$ of $S$. Next, there is a distinct symbol for every $n$-ary function of $S$. And last, there is also a distinct symbol for every $n$-ary relation on $S$. So, for example, on the set $\{0,1\}$, the total structure of $\{0,1\}$ includes the constants $0$ and $1$, all unary, binary, ternary, etc relations on $\{0,1\}$, and all unary, binary, ternary, etc operations on $\{0,1\}$. Has this definition been mentioned in the mathematical literature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this construction has a name. I have seen applied sometime to obtain (trivially) that all types over $S$ are definable.

Ofcouse if $S$ is infinite no elementary extension of it is "total".

Comment: It's also applied (somewhat) nontrivially, e.g. in nonstandard analysis we usually take an ultrapower of $\mathbb{R}$ equipped with all functions/relations/sets/constants.

Comment: Here's another application of this concept: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1535200/7062 Andreas Blass says in his answer that this concept is sometimes called the "full structure" on a set.